# iOS Universal App layout all messed up on iPhone?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, xcode6, ios-universal-app

I am trying to make a universal app in Xcode 6 using swift, and it's not going so well. I have a tab bar controller app, and I am trying to make something like this: [image]

(The height and width are set to Any) But when I run it on an iPhone 5 simulator:[image]

How do I fix this? Will I have to make separate storyboards for each device?

Comment: This can be done easily using AutoLayout, you need not add separate storyboards for each device. Refer to the answer if it helps

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by clicking on all of my items, then clicking on this guy near the bottom: [image]Then clicking "Reset to suggested constraints".

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is that, you should probably pin `Top Space` for the top most label and pin `Vertical Spacing` constraints for the other two buttons.

The "GO" button should have a vertical spacing constraint with respect to the "Control" label and the "STOP" should have a vertical spacing constraint with respect to the "GO" button or `Bottom Space`if you want to stick it to the bottom of the view.